# Minimizing of window in pyqtgraph resizes contained objects, but it should show just a smaller range of the graph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I am currently working on a project, which displays rectangle objects in pyqtgraph. When I am minimizing my window, the objects contained will also get resized, so that all objects are still visible. My problem is that I want the objects to keep their size and just to show a smaller range of the overall graph. Any ideas how I can fix my issue?

Original - Image:

[image: Original - Image]

Minimized - Image:

[image: Minimized - Image]

Code snippet:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

data = [(100, 100), (100, 550), (350,100), (350,550)]

# Creating Rectangle objects

class Rect(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, data):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
        self.generatePicture()
    
    def generatePicture(self):
        ## pre-computing a QPicture object allows paint() to run much more quickly, 
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        self.p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        self.p.setFont(QFont("times",50))
        self.p.setPen(pg.mkPen('b'))
        self.p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g')) 
        for index in self.data:
            self.p.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(index[0],index[1],250,450))
        self.p.end()
        
    
    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)
        
    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())

    
pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
  
w = pg.GraphicsWindow()
w.setWindowTitle('Rectangle - Display')
v = w.addViewBox()
v.setAspectLocked()
w.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 900)

v.addItem(Rect(data))

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a QScrollArea as a container widget and the GraphicsWindow can have a fixed size, then only the size of the QScrollArea will be changed.

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui

data = [(100, 100), (100, 550), (350, 100), (350, 550)]

# Creating Rectangle objects


class Rect(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, data):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
        self.generatePicture()

    def generatePicture(self):
        ## pre-computing a QPicture object allows paint() to run much more quickly,
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setFont(QtGui.QFont("times", 50))
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen("b"))
        p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush("g"))
        for index in self.data:
            p.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(*index, 250, 450))
        p.end()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())


pg.setConfigOption("background", "w")
pg.setConfigOption("foreground", "k")


w = pg.GraphicsWindow()
w.setWindowTitle("Rectangle - Display")
v = w.addViewBox()
# Disable the zoom implemented by the mouse wheel
v.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
v.setAspectLocked()
w.setFixedSize(1000, 900)

v.addItem(Rect(data))

scroll_area = QtGui.QScrollArea()
scroll_area.setWidget(w)
scroll_area.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 900)
scroll_area.show()

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, "PYQT_VERSION"):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```